# django-sphinx - settings has no attribute DATABASE_ENGINE -

Tags: python, django

When I am running the command:

```
  ./manage.py generate_sphinx_config cities >> sphinx.conf
```

It is returning error, that settings has no attribute DATABASE_ENGINE. I checking in shell also, I cant find DATABASE_ENGINE in settings. during setup, I had setup DATABASES.

DATABASE_ENGINE is used here: https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx/blob/master/djangosphinx/utils/config.py

```
  def _get_database_engine():
if settings.DATABASE_ENGINE == 'mysql':
    return settings.DATABASE_ENGINE
elif settings.DATABASE_ENGINE.startswith('postgresql'):
    return 'pgsql'
raise ValueError, "Only MySQL and PostgreSQL engines are supported by Sphinx."
```

Comment: It means django-sphinx needs to be updated. Django now uses a DATABASES variable instead of multiple variable names.

Comment: @SimeonVisser ok, what do you prefer. This one or haystack?

Comment: Sphinx is for documentation, Haystack is for search so you're compared apples and oranges here.

Comment: No, please look at the docs. https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx .

Comment: Ah, confusing, two tools in Python realm named Sphinx :) In that case Haystack but only because I have experience with that and not Sphinx search. So I can't really compare.